# CakePHP editing model data, best practice?

Tags: php, cakephp

So basically I'm struggling between 2 methods of changing model data.

Method 1: (function changes it directly in the model data)

```
$this->Model->set($data);
$this->Model->changeSomeData();
```

Method 2: (function with input and output)

```
$data = $this->Model->data;
$newdata = $this->Model->changeSomeData($data);
$this->Model->set($newdata);
```

Can someone shine some light on this, on what to use and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is a legacy issue with Cake 1.x where calling `Model->set($data)` was common practice. I would guess it happen because `validate()`, `create()` and `save()` needed to have the `id` or `data` assigned to the model.

As the code matured this practice became obsolete as `save()` would accept `$data` and also perform validation.

The problem here is that CakePHP merged the model and entity into a single class. A good database layout would separate model and entity. Which is what I think they're doing with Cake 3.x

Another problem is that Cake uses caches for model instances. It's possible that two unrelated classes could change a model's data because they share the same reference.

So I would strongly recommend method #2.

The code is easier to read, and easier to maintain.